# Rebinding tmux prefix to alt key

Tags: terminal, macros, command-line-interface, tmux, key-bindings

I'd like to change the tmux prefix from `ctrl+b` to a single key, specifically `alt`. Tried `set-option -g prefix M`, but it said bad key.

Anyone know how to accomplish this without having to create a macro on my entire system making `alt` trigger `ctrl+b`?

I'd settle for a macro that only triggers when inside of a tmux session.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround is to use tmux's root table instead of the prefix key table (see `bind-key` in man page). To do this, you need to pass the `-n` argument to the `bind-key` command. This does imply that you will have to re-bind all the commands in your `.tmux.conf` that you want to support.

An example of how to create a window using `alt+c` is:

```
bind -n M-c new-window
```